# Windows 10 folder is more than 100gb and drive is full

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-10-upgrade

My laptop is running windows 10 and everday it goes for update. now whole C:/windows/ is more than 100 GB. I don't know how to reduce this folder size ( don't what folders to delete ). I cannot repartition hard disk as all windows files belong to disk 0 and other partitions are in disk 1. Is someone facing same issue any solution you followed?

[disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9faH.png)

Comment: Did you try Disk Cleanup?

Comment: I flagged this question since understanding your disk usage is answered by the duplicate.  Once you know the reason the disk usage that can be a different question (provide information is provided)